# Can MappedTable be defined dynamically at runtime?

Tags: java, jooq

I've been a happy jOOQ user for a while now. In my application, I never update or delete anything. I always insert a new row, so that the whole history is always available. The application has a time-machine mode that allows to see the data as it was on a given day.

Schema for an entity is something like

- `entity` table

  - `id`
  - all the immutable properties of the entity
  - `inserted_at` timestamp of the insert
- `entity_updates` table

  - `id`
  - `entity_id`: fk to the `entity`
  - all the mutable properties
  - `inserted_at`: timestamp of the insert

By filtering on the `inserted_at` columns, I can make my time-machine work.

All is fine, but with more data, the application performance is worsening. I'd like to take shortcuts.

I consider doing the following:

- keeping up to date a table with the latest version of the data (same schema as the live table, kept in sync with DB triggers): the `entity_update_latest` table
- dynamically decide whether to hit the `entity_update_latest` table, of the `entity_update` table depending on the use case

To dynamically decide, I consider resorting to `MappedTable` in my jOOQ configuration.

Is there any caching layer in the usage of `MappedTable`, or would it be safe to have my own implementation of `MappedTable` that dynamically decides which table to hit based on some context information?

I was considering doing that with a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any caching layer in the usage of MappedTable

Yes, otherwise, the lookups would be relatively slow, at least in benchmarks. The cache is located in your `Configuration`.

If you want to bypass the cache, you could create a new `Configuration` per query, but most examples out there suggest you inject a single `Configuration` instance, as all caches are located in there.

But from how I understand your requirements, you won't flush the cache on a per-query basis, but maybe once per hour / per day? It should be fine to create a new `Configuration` at that interval.

> or would it be safe to have my own implementation of MappedTable that dynamically decides which table to hit based on some context information

No, that proxy wouldn't work, at least not in jOOQ 3.16